# Is initWithNibName and initWithCoder method of UIView or UIViewController?

Tags: cocoa-touch

It seems that I saw them in both. Which is funny given that they do not inherit from one another. Also they do have some common ancestor, but which one owns initWithCoder and iniwWithNibName?

So what gives?

Also in UIViewController reference class initWithCoder is not mentioned at all

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    //NSString * superClass =NSStringFromClass([self superclass]) ;
    self = [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: UITextField and UILabel dont inherit from each other but they both have a `text` property. Is it a UILabel property or a UITextField property?

Comment: They both inherit from UIView.

Comment: Since when did UIView have a `text` property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions like this should start with a search in the reference docs.

`initWithNibName:bundle:` is a method of `UIViewController` and no other class (other than classes that extend `UIViewController`).

`initWithCoder:` is a method declared in the `NSCoding` protocol. Any class (and there are MANY) that conform to the `NSCoding` protocol will have an `initWithCoder:` method. Both `UIView` and `UIViewController` implement the `NSCoding` protocol which means both classes have `initWithCoder:`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I checked the reference. initWithCoder doesn't seem to be a member of UIViewController. Now I know it's a member of a protocol that both UIViewController and UIView has.

Comment: And you think this is a bad question? People would normally think that initWithCoder has something to do with xib because they are called when UIView or UIViewController shows up in xib. Turns out they have something to do with NSCoding that has little to do with XIB in general. I think this is useful for many.

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus I never said it was a bad question. Why did you say that?

Comment: If your comment was about the downvote on your question then you should have posted your comment on the question, not my answer. And no, I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: `initWithCoder` (`NSCoding` protocol) allows objects, view controllers in this case, to be serialized and deserialized at will. Why would system want to serialize/deserialize view controllers? One thing that comes to my mind: memory. If app is making use of lots objects and heap goes up, system may decide to purge certain view controllers not used at this moment in your app, and recreate them later (by calling of course `initWithCoder`) when user navigates back to these view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

initWithCoder 、 initWithNibName all means that you can use the .xib file to create view .

Comment: `initWithCoder:` means a lot more than being able to use with a xib.